# Why isn't $\sqrt{2} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{1}$ rational?

Tags: irrational-numbers

Well, I know that $\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number and I am also familiar with the proof by contradiction method, but I'm confused by this notation as we can divide $\sqrt{2}$ by $1$ (as $\sqrt{2}$ is a real number and for a real number it is possible) and will get $\sqrt{2}$, so can't $\sqrt{2}$ be written as $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1}$, and in that case $\sqrt{2}$ should be a rational number.

Comment: A rational number needs to be something you can write as $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ and $q$ are both *integers*, not real numbers, and $\sqrt{2}$ isn't an integer, so that doesn't qualify.

Comment: Rational numbers are those numbers who can be written as an **integer** divided by another integer.  $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1}$ does not satisfy this requirement since the numerator is not an integer.  Whether or not a number can be written as a *real* divided by another real is irrelevant.

Comment: And yes, we can of course divide $\sqrt{2}$ by $1$ and it be equal to the original number.  That doesn't say anything about its rationality however.

Comment: I think you should read about Dedekind cuts to see what irrational numbers can be.

Comment: @Emil You are suggesting learning about dedekind cuts to someone who asked a question of this level?  Certainly not... that will only confuse them further.  Let them learn math for another decade first.

Comment: @JMorawitz: yes, I think diving in the deep end is good for you. I did not hear about it until several years after my engineering studies when I was autodidacting myself to make up for math I did not learn in uni.

Comment: @Emil There is a certain level of required "*[mathematical maturity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_maturity)*" here.  You don't try to teach a child about french baking techniques when they are confused by the concept that different powders are different ingredients and don't know how to boil water on their own.  Letting them know that such techniques exist and that there are results, sure, but they aren't ready yet to understand or appreciate any of the details involved.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Often mathematical ideas are really intuitive, I did not ask him to apply it for goodness sake :-)

Comment: Well, thnx for answering my question,and for an interesting convo b/w u both :)

Comment: With this definition, EVERY real number would be rational.